# Error using ServiceStack.Text to deserialize derived generic type

Tags: c#, generics, deserialization, servicestack-text

I'm using ServiceStack.Text to serialize/deserialize objects before storing them in Redis, but i've come across some objects, that won't deserialize as expected.

I have a base type (bit of legacy code, with many projects using this base type) with a property of type object. Later a generic version of the base type have been added, exposing the property as a generic type.

Using ServiceStack.Text to serialize and deserialize the generic type sets the property on the base class (type object) and not the more specific type on the derived class.

A simple console app to reproduce the errors goes something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public class Base<T> : Base
    {
        //hide the Value property on the base class
        public new T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Base
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Base<List<string>>()
        {
            Value = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" },
        };

        var serialized = TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(a);
        var deserialized = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Base<List<string>>>(serialized);

        //throws a null ref exception
        Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Value.Count);
    }
}
```

Setting a breakpoint after deserialization, Visual Studio shows the object with base.Value as the List<string> with the value of the serialized list, but the Value property on my Base<List<String>> class is null.

[Screenshot of debugger in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydJxz.png)

Is there any way to configure TypeSerializer (or JsonSerializer) to correctly set to more specific property instead of the property on the base class?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

Based on the answer, i solved it by making the `Base<T>` and `Base` inherit from a new abstract base class, like so:

```
public abstract class DummyBase
{
    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";
}

public class BaseResponse<T> : DummyBase
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResponse : DummyBase
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Base.Value is hidden, it's still visible to reflection (eg with `a.GetType().GetProperties()`. That could be the problem.

The following seems to work. The getters and setters in `Base<T>` just wrap `Base.Value`. `DummyBase<T>` is necessary to get ServiceStack to deserialize the string to the correct type.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Base<List<string>>()
        {
            Value = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" },
        };

        var serialized = TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(a);
        var deserialized = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<DummyBase<List<string>>>(serialized);

        // no longer throws a null ref exception
        Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Value.Count);
    }
}

public class DummyBase<T> 
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Base<T> : Base
{ 
    public new T Value 
    {
        get { return (T)base.Value; }
        set { base.Value = value; }
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, all this wouldn't be necessary if `Base<T>` didn't inherit from `Base`.

Comment: I have some dependent project, that expects the type of `Base<T>` so returning `DummyBase<T>` is not exactly what i want, but pointed me in the right direction. The base class has additional properties and methods, but making the `DummyBase` the base of both the generic and non-generic class makes it work.